# Grid row height is not calculated correctly in Chrome when justify-content is set to space-between, Is this a bug?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-grid

I have a grid container which has 3 columns and 6 child items. When i set the 'justify-content' property of this container to 'space-between', the grid element is not displayed properly. in Firefox everything is fine but in Chrome it seems that the height of rows is not calculated properly and the heights are less than expected.
Here is my code which shows the problem:

```css
.container {
  background-color: #69D1C5;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(auto, 200px));
  justify-content: space-between;
  gap: 10px
}

.container .item {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #8980F5;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">
    Spectacular ice age wolf pup and caribou dug up in Canada
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Plant roots evolved at least twice, and step by step
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Spectacular ice age wolf pup and caribou dug up in Canada Spectacular ice age wolf pup and caribou dug up in Canada
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Plant roots evolved at least twice, and step by step
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Plant roots evolved at least twice, and step by step Plant roots evolved at least twice, and step by step
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    Plant roots evolved at least twice, and step by step
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is the Codepen link: [link](https://codepen.io/Nasab187/pen/WgYjZK)

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem. Your code renders the same in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: @Michael_B How did you test it? if you've tested it from the 'Run code snippet', make sure to check it in full-page mode to see the problem.

Comment: I did. Also checked your codepen on Chrome and Firefox. What am I missing? I don't see any difference whatsoever.

Comment: @Michael_B I don't know. Perhaps version of chrome browser differs. I use Chrome version 69.

Comment: @Michael_B the text is overflowing .. I am able to reproduce on chrome, probably the last version is having issue (69)